# How to use CSV files to invite friends to your company page on Facebook

Tags: facebook-pages

I want to invite more friends to my company page on Facebook using a CSV file but it is not working for me. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have emails, in csv, you can use 
Build Auddience > Invite Email Contacts > Other tools
you have also some information about it if you click 
How to create a contact file... > Other

Comment: I've tried this many times but my invitations are not sent to the person I'd like to invite. Any suggestions?